# Match strings using regular expressions but ignore (not exclude) certain phrases containing the matched string

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to find a way to match certain strings within a dataset, but ignore (not exclude) some expressions that contain a match.

```
clin_pres <- c("Patient A received yellow fever vaccine, and had a fever", "Patient B received the yellow fever vaccine but had no fever", "Patient C returned from Bali yesterday and now has a fever", "Patient D had no fever last week but now has a fever")
```

So in this example, I would like to find all matches with the word "fever", but ignore matches with the strings "yellow fever vaccine" or "no fever"

I know I can do

```
grepl("fever",clin_pres, ignore.case = TRUE) & !grepl("yellow fever vaccine",clin_pres, ignore.case = TRUE) & !grepl("no fever",clin_pres, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Which outputs:
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

But I just want to ignore "yellow fever vaccine" and "no fever" as matches, not exclude them when matched, to obtain output:
[1] TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE

Any help or suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible regex solutions:

```
grepl("\\b(?<!\\bno )fever\\b(?<!\\byellow fever(?= vaccine))",clin_pres, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

Or, a bit more flexible solution where the number of whitespaces may be any between the words:

```
grepl("(?:\\b(?:no\\s+fever|yellow\\s+fever\\s+vaccine)\\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|\\bfever\\b",clin_pres, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/GMAT97100).

The first - `\\b(?<!\\bno )fever\\b(?<!\\byellow fever(?= vaccine))`  - regex matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\bno )` - no "no " allowed right before
- `fever` - a word
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\byellow fever(?= vaccine))` - no "yellow " before "fever" and no " vaccine" after `fever`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NrwZh7/1).

The second one is actually simpler:

- `(?:\b(?:no\s+fever|yellow\s+fever\s+vaccine)\b)` - `no fever` or `yellow fever vaccine` as whole words with any 1+ whitespaces in between the words
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - skip the match at the current position, and go on searching for a match from it
- `|` - or
- `\bfever\b` - a whole word `fever`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NrwZh7/2)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the strings not wanted and then grep for fever:

```
grepl("fever", gsub("yellow fever vaccine|no fever", "", clin_pres))
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The question used `ignore.case = TRUE` but that is not needed since the input is all lower case. If you did have upper case letters in another problem just replace `clin_pres` with `tolower(clin_pres)` or alternatively add `ignore.case=TRUE` to both the `grepl` and `gsub`.

Comment: I don't think this should have been downvoted. It answers the question, gives the correct answer , is easy to generalize and is much simpler than any other answer given.